# To change the div style in css file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I want to change the background color with a background image in my plugin. While selecting the radio button in wordpress. when changing the color of the div it should update the css file.

I want to update

```
.wrap_div{
    background:#9CF;
    float: left;
    width: 584px;
}
```

the div style with the below one.

```
   .wrap_div{

            float: left;
            width: 584px;           
        background-image:url(./images/back2.png);    

    }
```

How can I make changes in my css file. Any help is appreciated.The wrap_div is a user side div.I am using this code in admin side and I want the changes should appear in user side.

Comment: you cannot update css file dynamically. Do  it in Jquery or Javascript

Comment: Can't be done, not with PHP at least.  PHP is server side and what you need to happen needs to happen on a client event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the element to another class,changing css file is really not a good option,speaking from experience...

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the style in your document `<head>` directly using the [`wp_head`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) hook.

```
function print_styles(){
echo '<style>';
#write PHP code to display your styles here
echo '</style>';
}

add_action('wp_head', 'print_styles');
```

Answer (score 0):

create a php file with css structure which you will update from server and import it in your style.css with `@import 'css/style.css.php?c=1';`

Your php file should look like this:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/css');

.wrap_div {
 echo $styles'
}
?>
```

Comment: also, the OptionTree plugin has some functions that will update your css file directly, but it probably rewrites the whole file every time you save the options

Answer (score 0):

update your css file by

```
.wrap_div_radio_change{
margin:0 auto; 
width:410px; 
height:460px; 
background-image:url(./images/back2.png);    
clear:both; 
border:#000000 solid 1px;
}
```

And use this script

```
if($('#radio_button').is(':checked')) {//Id of you radio button
   $("#your_div").removeClass('wrap_div');//Id of the div which has the color to change Which will remove the initial clas of the div and the next line add a new class to the div
   $("#your_div").addClass('wrap_div_radio_change');
  }
```

Comment: to change only the background:#9CF; with background-image:url(./images/back2.png); for that div.what to do?

Comment: $("#your_div").css("background", "url('images/back2.png')");

Answer (score 0):

By using JavaScript, you can try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
    .red{
        background-color:red;
    }

    .blue{
        background-color:blue;
    }

    .green{
        background-color:green;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeColor(color) {
            document.getElementById("wrap_div").setAttribute("class", color.value);
        }
    </script>
    <div id="wrap_div">
    Red <input type="radio" value="red" name="color" onClick="changeColor(this);"><br>
    Blue <input type="radio" value="blue" name="color" onClick="changeColor(this);"><br>
    Green <input type="radio" value="green" name="color" onClick="changeColor(this);">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use following code.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

 jQuery('input:radio[name="radioname"]').change(function(){

 jQuery('.wrap_div').css('background','');
 jQuery('.wrap_div').css('background-image','url(./images/back2.png)');
});

});

</script>
```

Also add other css style like this using .css.